# How do I start a program with a hotkey after I started another

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I want my program to start by pressing a hotkey, but only if another specific program has already been started, like for example, when I started fraps and then want to start a game after some minutes.

What commands should I use in a .bat file?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
@echo off
start /w cmd /c myapp.exe
timeout 60
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (app2) else (timeout 60)
```

Comments: timeout 60 - is 60 secs of waiting;
tasklist line checks if the app has started - if yes - starts the second one, if not - adds one more minute timeout.